# Firebird: Tracing the culprit behind the message length error (encountered X, expected Y)

Tags: database, backup, firebird, firebird2.5

When running the backup using the **gbak** utility the process terminates with the error:

> gbak: writing data for table THE_TABLE
>
> **message length error** (encountered 326, expected 322)

The error [can](https://www.mail-archive.com/ru-firebird@googlegroups.com/msg09243.html) appear due to IBExpert's ability to change the columns structure silently (size, type), so the situation is possible where the schema and related data are incompatible.

The changes made to the database schema weren't logged. I don't know if there were column type changes.

I looked at the tables's varchar columns. The lengths of those columns are 22, 22, 20, 20, 20 and 80 symbols. Сollate and charset options are set to WIN1251 for those columns. As far as I understand for WIN1251 it's a 1 byte per char. Thinking this way I should look for a column with **expected** 322 characters. Maybe there's another source for that error?

How do I find the point where the overflow takes place?

Comment: `WIN1251 ` => http://www.sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: `Сollate and charset options are set to WIN1251` - they could be different for prior formats, not only lengths - charsets could be different. If they were UTF-$ for example, then 320=80x4 // u may try to look into `RDB$FORMATS` https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx04-systables.html

Comment: `Select MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(Field_A)) from the_table` then same with `FIELD_B` and so forth. Then with `BYTE_LENGTH` instead of `CHAR_LENGTH`. And see on which fields it would fail.

Comment: @Arioch'The I also thought about the 80x4=320, given that there could be utf-8 charset from the start. But why 322 bytes are expected then? Where those 2 additional bytes come from?

Comment: Dunno. There was a PDF about low-level FDB file format, also there is `API Guide` showcasinf unpacked rows layout in memory. For example it may be that 15 bits (well known 32KBytes limit) length of Char/VarChar column. Or anything.

Comment: @Arioch'The Checked all my varchar columns, unfortunately) no errors.

Comment: Well, check the table formats history and if no honey then  try to ask for more in-depth suggestions on the FB forum at first link

Comment: @Arioch'The Ok, I'll surely do this & thank you.